# How to notify the user about unsaved changes made in a HTML page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page and it contains input text items with 5X5 dimension
(5rows and 5 coulms).
The requirement is whenever the user moves away with submitting the changes the user is required to notify about unsaved changes

A javascript alert is sufficient but the problem is
there are about 10 tabs and 12 sub menu items. Do I need to add
'on click' function on all of these tab/menu items or is there
any other alternative..

Thanks

Comment: Don't add `onclick=`. Just use jQuery or raw JS, loop over your elements, and attach event handlers.

Comment: Are you using JavaScript libraries. I have an easy jQuery solution i use in production environment.

Comment: What do you mean by "move away"?

Comment: @Zirak, whenever user clicks any other link other than 'Submit' button is what is the meaning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I am trying for [window.onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload) Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: That'll fire if when the user is about to leave the page. If that's what you want, then yes.